# tabplot visualization pkg: what is the left-side 0 -100% vertical axis?

Tags: r, user-interface, plot, visualization

Using the "tabplot" pkg.
with the simple iris data set example:

```
**#load required packages**
require(ggplot2)
require(tabplot)
**# import data set**
data(iris)

**# make the plot**
tableplot(iris, sortCol="Species")
```

*So, my Q:*
what does the vertical scale (0% to 100%)
on the left-side of the plot, represent?
What does it mean?

I searched in vain for a clear explanation in plain English,
(for a tin-head like me).

Would somebody care to explain it
in clear, "everyday" terms   for this simple iris example?
*thanks!!*

Comment: The vertical scale represents the percentage of the whole data set that the sortCol factor represents.  Here, each Species numbers 50, so each is one-third of the total.

Comment: @lawyeR  Clear! hey,  thanks...and +1 for your handle.

Comment: The iris example (above) has sortCol="Species"  which is a Factor with 3 possible categories.  But...what would the vertical % axis represent, if we used the "diamonds" data set with sortCol="carat" ( a continuous#) ?

Comment: The plot bins the data set by carets, showing 539 per bin, and shows on the vertical, y-axis, what percentage of all the diamonds fall into each of the 100 row bins.

Comment: @ lawyeR Ace! thanks again,  lawyeR. This coffee is for you! :-)

Comment: Well, for cream in my coffee, so to speak, should I wrap the comments up more elegantly in an answer for you to accept?  Subtle, aren't I ...

Comment: Yes, please do!  It was easier for me to understand your first answer (for the iris example with 3 Species categories) . -- The second answer regarding the diamonds dataset (using the continuous value of Carets as sortCol), is still slightly harder to grasp. Maybe if you include a concrete example for diamonds in your wrap-up answer, (as you did in the previous  iris answer) would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical scale on the left of a `tableplot` represents the percentage of the whole data set that the sortCol factor displays. With the iris data set, each Species numbers 50, so each species accounts for one-third of the total 100%.

With the diamonds data set, if `sortCol` is set to carets, the plot bins the data set by carets, showing the aggregate of 539 per bin, and shows on the vertical, y-axis, what percentage of all the diamonds fall into each of the 100 bins.

Comment: @ lawyeR ok, answer approved! The system tells me I'm too new to StackO to add votes, yet. Will upvote your good answer when they allow me to!    btw: in the 2nd paragraph, when you say: "...the aggregate of 539 per bin", do you mean: a) "...539 records per bin"  -or-  b) "...539 different caret values per bin"?

Comment: Thanks.  It is a) meaning 539 diamonds per bin.

Comment: thanks @ lawyeR - all clear now. Also, was finally able to up-vote your answer!  Finally... :-)  the coffee with cream is served...er, statistically speaking, of course...